# Parse all but a few nodes with certain attribute values

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

Using elementtree, is there a easy way to parse the entire xml document except those text that are on nodes that have some particular attribute value. As an example I would like to parse the file except for when attribute `name="Liechtenstein"`and when attribute `month="08"`

```
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <language>english</language>
        <currency>1.21$/kg</currency> 
        <gdppc month="06">141100</gdppc>
        <gdpnp month="10">2.304e+0150</gdpnp>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <language>english</language>
        <currency>4.1$/kg</currency> 
        <gdppc month="05">59900</gdppc>
        <gdpnp month="08">5.2e-015</gdpnp>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Lahore">
        <rank updated="yes">8</rank>
        <language>Pertr</language>
        <currency>7.3$/kg</currency> 
        <gdppc month="010">34000</gdppc>
        <gdpnp month="099">3.4e+015</gdpnp>
        <neighbor name="Peru" direction="N"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Based on the above, I would like to return the following `5`, `english`, `4.1$/kg`, `59900`, `8`, `Pertr`, `7.3$/kg`, `34000`, `3.4e+015`. I feel one can use `iterparse` but I do not know how to go about this. 
Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: you are using `import xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse ??

Comment: Yes vivek, the problem is that i need to do this dynamically and the xml is deeply nested. The unwanted names and attributes can be in any hierarchy not in the particular order shown here. Is there a way to do `//*[not(@08 or 09 or 10)]` as in xpath using elementtree?

Comment: yes, just add ignore values in list i.e. ` ["08", "09", "10"]`.  but can you shear valid test case i.e. Input and respective Output on stackoverflow or email me vivekbsable@gmail.com ??

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `xml.etree.ElementTree` module to parse XML content.
2. Use `getiterator()` method to iterate only `country` tags.
3. Validate `country` tag.
4. Iterate children on selected `country` tag by `getchildren()` method.
5. Validate child for month validation.
6. Add values in tmp list.
7. Append tmp to main result list.

code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as PARSER
root = PARSER.fromstring(data)
result = []
for i in root.getiterator("country"):
    if  "name" in i.attrib and i.attrib["name"] not in ["Liechtenstein"]:
        tmp = []
        for j in i.getchildren():
            if "month" in j.attrib:
                if j.attrib["month"] not in ["08"]:
                    if j.text:
                        tmp.append(j.text)
            else:
                if j.text:
                    tmp.append(j.text)

        result.append(tmp)


print "result:-", result
```

Output:

```
:~/workspace/vivek$ python test3.py 
result:- [['5', 'english', '4.1$/kg', '59900'], ['8', 'Pertr', '7.3$/kg', '34000', '3.4e+015']]
```

---

By `lxml` module

Used `xpath()` method to get target `country` tag.

Code:

```
import lxml.html as PARSER
root = PARSER.fromstring(data)
result = []
print "debug 1 list of country: ", root.xpath("//country[@name!='Liechtenstein']")
for i in root.xpath("//country[@name!='Liechtenstein']"):
        tmp = []
        for j in i.getchildren():
            if "month" in j.attrib:
                if j.attrib["month"] not in ["08"]:
                    if j.text:
                        tmp.append(j.text)
            else:
                if j.text:
                    tmp.append(j.text)

        result.append(tmp)


print "result:-", result
```

Result:

```
:~/workspace/vtestproject$ python test3.py 
debug 1 list of country:  [<Element country at 0xb724da04>, <Element country at 0xb7257cac>]
result:- [['5', 'english', '4.1$/kg', '59900'], ['8', 'Pertr', '7.3$/kg', '34000', '3.4e+015']]
```